# I want to use the gpu of the HPC and try module add CUDA... But errors occurs. The error is "Lmod has detected the following error:

Tags: linux, module, lua, gpu, hpc

```
Lmod has detected the following error:  Unable to load module
because of error when evaluating modulefile:
     /trinity/shared/easybuild/modules/all/CUDA/11.1.1-GCC-10.2.0.lua: Empty or
non-existant file
     Please check the modulefile and especially if there is a the line number
specified in the above message
While processing the following module(s):
    Module fullname         Module Filename
    ---------------         ---------------
    CUDA/11.1.1-GCC-10.2.0  /trinity/shared/easybuild/modules/all/CUDA/11.1.1-GCC-10.2.0.lua
```

The error is confusing. I typed `rm –rf ~/.lmod.d/.cache` but it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you `cat /trinity/shared/easybuild/modules/all/CUDA/11.1.1-GCC-10.2.0.lua`?
Maybe your `modulefile` is not existent.

> if `modulefile` is not existent:
> Generally, you can write down `modulefile` with `lua` or `tcl` file. Try to make some file like this!

```
#%Module

set s /usr/local/cuda-11.1

prepend-path PATH $s/bin
prepend-path LIBRARY_PATH $s/lib
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH $s/lib
prepend-path LIBRARY_PATH $s/lib64
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH $s/lib64
prepend-path CPATH $s/include
prepend-path INCLUDE $s/include
```